# Prime numbers making constant : 1.2527

Tags: prime-numbers, constants

Reading "Excursion in calculus" (Robert M. Young, 1992), exercice 13 on page 71 ask the reader to show there is a constant $c\approx 1.25$ such that

1. $a_0=2^c$
2. $a_{n+1}=2^{a_n}$
3. $\forall n\; \lfloor a_n\rfloor$ is prime

This can be proved using [Bertrand's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate).

I found that $c\approx 1.2527$ is a good candidate as

- $\lfloor a_0\rfloor=2$
- $\lfloor a_1\rfloor=5$
- $\lfloor a_2\rfloor=37$
- $\lfloor a_3\rfloor=153703792531$ that is prime too.

There must be several different constants that have this property, but we can suppose that $c$ is minimal.

Does that constant has a name ? Does someone computed or is trying to compute more decimal ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This number is called *Bertrand's number* in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/); the decimal expansion is [OEIS A$079614$](http://oeis.org/A079614) and is

$$1.251647597790463017594432053623346969\ldots\;.$$

The sequence of associated primes is [OEIS A$051501$](http://oeis.org/A051501). There are references in both OEIS entries.